# Using alias name another columns list value

Tags: sql

I have table which looks like this

| A | B | c | list |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d2 | d3 | d4 | [key1,key2,key3] |
| d21 | d31 | d5 | [key1,key2,key4] |

I want to get the key name from the array list by indexing and assign the columnn name as alias,
so my final output table sould looks like this

| key1 | key2 | key3 | list |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d2 | d3 | d4 | [key1,key2,key3] |
| d21 | d31 | d5 | [key1,key2,key4] |

I know its silly but i have tried this

```
select 
A as array[0],
B as array[1],
C as array[2]
from table
```

obviously it didn't work , i am pretty new to SQL ( I am using clickhouse ) , is there a way to do it? , thank you

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: i am using clickhouse warehouse (column-oriented DBMS) but solution in any sql is fine

Comment: So you want the list column which contains list `[key1,key2,key3]` to be used as the alias? Apart from being horrible to want this, it will be horrible to implement it. You will have to run 2 queries, and either do some processing in the client application (eg C# or php) , or you need to use some procedure. First query will be for getting the list, and the second query will be created on the fly, using the correct aliases.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way, if the columns will not change is to hardcore it.

```
select 
A as "key1",
B as "key2",
C as "key3"
from table;
```

If this doesn't work for you please give the table definition and more sample data.